# How to debug system error in google data studio?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm working on a community connector, my fields are getting pulled in properly, but trying to use it in a report I get the following error below.

I'm less concerned about the specific error, but more concerned how I even figure out what is going on or breaking on the server.

Anyone figure out good ways to debug these errors?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What were the details?

Comment: Just added that, as you can see nothing very helpful. Looked up the error id, but don't find anything related to it.

Comment: I'm not a Data Studio user but I did a Google Search on `Data Studio System Error Error Id 81d8cc25` and you're evidently not alone in this problems. Read the search results and watch the video.  Hopefully that will help.  It looks like it could be difficult to find the answer.

Comment: You can use console.log in your app script code, and then look at the logs via the Executions panel of your app script project. This helps in some cases.

Comment: One such system error can be caused by field ID's that contain spaces or other disallowed characters. Data Studio will let you put these ID's into your schema, but then breaks when attempting to use them in a report. Make sure all your field ID's use only alphanumeric characters and no spaces. Use field names for user-facing display names.

Comment: Also note that (in my current experience) the Error ID changes every time you refresh data, so it does not actually seem to indicate anything about what type of error occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research on this and digging around. I found that it came down to an invalid schema. ugh. I noticed that the getData, wasn't even being ran when trying to use data from a report. This made me think it was failing elsewhere.

In my case I was a prebuilt json object, and passing that to the schema field for data studio. 
**Unfortunately google provides no feedback for mis-configured JSON schemas.**

:sigh:

I simplified the schema and found the issue was a incorrect data type. Once I fixed this all worked :)

This method is mentioned here, and even google data studio says its hard to debug.
https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/semantics

Its nice to have the schema seperate from code, but careful that the schema is correct otherwise you'll run into this very generic issue. Until they add more logging in this area.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my discover here just in case, I was with the same case, but in my case this problem was occurring in a Pie Chart, but the same Metric combined with another segmentation didn't appear this problem.

After some test I found which case generates the problem, my problem was happening because this metric, in a specific segmentation, generates a total value negative, what Pie Charts have problems to show.

My field has string and numeric values too, but this is not a problem (until now at least). To solve my problem I create a new field where negative values are replaced by 0 (this doesn't make impacts at insight I need, because this values I don't need to track or show them in a Pie Chart).

So my suggestion here is try to understand if it is happening with a specific segmentation, or all time. With this segmentation, try to create filters and display each segment only, if this problem occurs you will discover which segment creates the error. Try to check the field you are making of sum, mean, or anything else, if he have negative values. If it happens, Pie Chart is not a possibility to show that, or you need to filter, replace, make any rule.